# Publish subscribe for iOS?

Tags: ios, publish-subscribe

Is there pub sub support in the iOS SDK or in any framework for iOS (in essence a wrapper for `NSNotificationCenter`, that would facilitate use and also add additional functionality)?

I find pub sub very helpful for designing mobile applications and on Android I use [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) and found it very helpful for sharing application events (such as when temperature gets updated from a web service). Searching online, I have found only one framework ([bendytree](https://github.com/bendytree/PubSub-iOS) ) and it does not seem very active (only two commits).

Is this already built into the SDK, or is there a standard library commonly used? (Or maybe nobody does pub-sub on iOS?)

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using a managed cloud services like [Pusher](http://pusher.com) or [Realtime](http://framework.realtime.co/messaging)? They both implement publish/subscribe and have native iOS SDK's.

Comment: Thanks but that slightly different then what I'm looking for. Those services help with client to server communication. I am looking for a framework that works for in app communication. It gets very ugly if you have to use callbacks everywhere.

Comment: essentially what a good pub/sub library would be doing is wrapping NSNotificationCenter and adding additional functionality

Answer (score 0):

Try following samples. It works perfectly for me. These links will give solution for publish subscribe which is the advanced concept for `NSNotificationCenter`.

1. https://github.com/staxmanade/PubSub-iOS
2. https://github.com/Glow-Inc/GLPubSub